# Simple jQuery (scrollTo and animate) not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, scrollto

I just now noticed that some simple jQuery is not working on IE9 and IE10 for mobile.
I have some copyright links and simple sliding contact form which uses `animate()`.
Also I use scrollTo plugin in combination with jQuery. I tried different versions, and still no solution. Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Here is the code for one copyright link and for contact form to open and close.

```
$('#privacy').click(function(){
    $('#copyright').hide('fast');
    $('#policy').toggle('slow');
    $.scrollTo('+=800px', 800, { axis:'y' });
        });

$('#plusSign').click(function(){
    if ($('#contactFormHolder').hasClass('active')){
        $('#contactFormHolder').animate({top:'-200px'},1000).removeClass('active');
    }else{$('#contactFormHolder').animate({top:'0px'},1000).addClass('active');}
    
});
```

You can check it live on http://www.crazysunsets.com

Comment: Sounds like a bug your should report to the `$.scrollTo` plugin developer.

Comment: IE 9 and IE 10 for mobile? Are you using a Windows Phone?

Comment: Yes, the popular scrollTo plugin by Ariel Fiesler

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, Lumia820

Comment: @Blazemonger But why the simple animate() when clicked on plus sign doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, specifically the script tag format:

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript ">
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Remove the space after 'javascript'

Cheers!

Comment: Such a simple thing gone unnoticed! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

goto bottom path:
tools menu=>internet Option=>Advanced Tab=>in setting list=>in browsing group

unchecked the "Disable script debbugging(ie)" and "Disable script debbugging(others)" options(checkboxes).
now refresh page. ie send error line and error name for you!

Comment: saved me a lot of money hiring another developer to do the same thin thanks