# Jquery code not working on IE and firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I've made a small jQuery code, which works on Chrome and Opera, but not on IE and Firefox.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($('body')[0].scrollTop / $('body')[0].scrollHeight > 0.29) {
     $(".over_one").fadeIn(2000);
    } else {
     $(".over_one").fadeOut(1);
    }
   });
</script>
```

I have also searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505714/simple-jquery-not-working-in-ie) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174120/jquery-is-not-working-in-firefox), but this was not fixing my problem.

Comment: Have you tried the equivalent jQuery methods for accessing those properties? `scrollHeight` is not supported on all browsers.

Comment: Browsers use different elements for scrolling. Some use `html`, others `body`. You code looks like it could suffer from it, apart from what @Filype found. (Although "does not work" is kind of a vague error description, given that we don't know what you want to achieve.)

Comment: I fixed it guys, i've add the `'html, body'` to `.scrollHeight` and deleted the `.scrollTop`, thanks for your help @Boldewyn, @TrueBlueAussie and @Filype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a `src` attribute and javascript code inside the script tag. This should be separated into 2 script tags.

Generally what you posted is written as: (though that may not be the problem)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('body')[0].scrollTop / $('body')[0].scrollHeight > 0.29) {
    $(".over_one").fadeIn(2000);
  } else {
    $(".over_one").fadeOut(1);
  }
});
</script>
```